# tcsh alias with if-then-else condition

Tags: linux, alias, tcsh

I am trying to have an alias with if-then-else condition
on a command result.

1. the alias will get a file pattern
2. if there is just one file it will open the file
3. if there is more or less then 1 files - it will indicate with a message.

the alias I have tried is:

```
alias atest 'if \("ls \!:1" > 0 \)  "nedit ls \!:1" else "echo cant open the file" '
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it with an alias. Use a shell script.

Comment: When you put `ls \!:1` in quotes, it doesn't execute the command. So you're just comparing the string to `0`, not counting the number of files that match the pattern.

Comment: You need something like `\`ls \!:1 | wc -l\` ` to count the number of lines printed by the command.

Comment: I have tried the following but got an error: 
alias atest 'if \(`ls \!:1` > 0 \)  "nedit ls \!:1" else "echo cant open the file" '

if: Expression Syntax.

Comment: LIke I said, you can't do it with an alias. `if` has to be on multiple lines, but an alias can only be one line.

Comment: @Barmar , Actually, multiline aliases work with tcsh pretty well. I use such aliases for years. Just write them really using multiple lines with backslash at the end of each line.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with an alias. An alias can only expand into a one-line command, but `if` requires multiple lines.

Instead, use a shell script. The script doesn't have to be in the same language you use interactively, so you can use POSIX shell, which is generally considered much better for programming than C shell (see [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)).

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then nedit "$1"
else 
    echo "Can't open the file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Put this in a file named `atest`, give it execute permissions, and put it in a directory that's in your `$PATH`.

Comment: You could also use `alias atest source ~/.tcsh/atest.tcsh` (this has the downside that you need to be careful to not clobber the global shell state though, although modifying the shell state could also be a feature in some cases).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I haven't used tcsh in a long time. Can a script executed with `source` access command-line parameters?

Comment: Not directly but you can set variables in the parent script which the sourced script can read.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker What parent script? aliases are generally used interactively. This alias is supposed to count the number of files matched by the wildcard when he types `atest foo*` -- how will `foo*` get into the sourced script?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways, most of them are not very elegant, but the following is the best looking and easiest to create that I have discovered:

```
alias aliasname '`if (condition == check) echo "echo"` >&/dev/null && code_if_true || code_if_false'
```

You have the ability to nest if statements following this format, and can also use it as a checker for arguments if you change the interior of the if statement to be

```
if ("\!:1" =~ "check")
```

The >&/dev/null is to clean up the output of the function, but is not necessary. If you are interested, there is also a way to make for statements within aliases, but that method is a lot less elegant. I haven't used it but it is necessary if you wish to create an alias with a varying number of arguments. Again, that one is ugly, so at that point I'd just write a function.

Comment: My shell is csh, not tcsh. I found your code works when `code_if_true` does not contain `cd` command. However, if I use `cd` command in `cod_if_true`, then `code_if_false` will not be excuted when the condition is false.

Comment: My alias is `alias t '\`if ( $PWD != $HOME ) echo "echo"\`>&/dev/null && cd || echo "home"'`. When at home dir, the message is not printed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, tcsh can have aliases with multiple lines in them. Just finish each line with backslash () and continue writing the alias on a next line.

```
~> alias atest 'set __atest_pattern="\!:1"                       \
?  set __atest_files=( "`ls -d $__atest_pattern`" )              \
?  if ( $#__atest_files == 1 ) then                              \
?      nedit "$__atest_files[1]"                                 \
?  else if ( $#__atest_files > 1 ) then                          \
?      echo "Too many files ($#__atest_files) are matched to '\''$__atest_pattern'\''"    \
?  endif'

~> alias atest
set __atest_pattern="!:1"                                                            
set __atest_files=( "`ls -d $__atest_pattern`" )                                      
if ( $#__atest_files == 1 ) then                                                      
    nedit "$__atest_files[1]"                                                          
else if ( $#__atest_files > 1 ) then                                                  
    echo "Too many files ($#__atest_files) are matched to '$__atest_pattern'"    
endif

~> atest *
Too many files (73) are matched to '*'
~> atest dummy
ls: cannot access dummy: No such file or directory
~> atest /dummy/*
ls: No match.
~> atest .cshrc
# Actually nedit was invoked here
~>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jonathan Roberts solution. This is part of a bash script on the local server. Checks for user XXXXX if true, sends through ssh the BASH command. Otherwise sends the TCSH command. The command checks to see if a directory exists returns true or false

```
if [[ ${LOCAL_USER} == "XXXXX" ]]; then
   LOCAL_DIR_EXIST_CHECK=$(ssh -v -q -i ~/.ssh/"${LOCAL_SSH_KEY_FILE}" "${LOCAL_USER}@${LOCAL_SERVER}" "if [[ -d ${LOCAL_CLIENT_DIRECTORY} ]];then echo 'TRUE'; else echo 'FALSE'; fi")
else
   LOCAL_DIR_EXIST_CHECK=$(ssh -v -q -i ~/.ssh/"${LOCAL_SSH_KEY_FILE}" "${LOCAL_USER}@${LOCAL_SERVER}" '`if ( -d ' ${LOCAL_CLIENT_DIRECTORY} ') echo "echo"` > & /dev/null && echo TRUE || echo FALSE')
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @JonathanRoberts answer I was able to finally improve an alias for `exit` that I use in shells inside `screen` so that I don't accidentally **exit** when I really want to **detach**.  So, now I can override the faked exit with `exit now` if I want and really exit:

In `~/.tcshrc`

```
if ($?TERM && $TERM =~ screen.*) then
    #OLD ALIAS# alias exit "echo 'exit disabled (via alias)'; screen -d"
    alias exit '`if ("\!:$" == "now") echo "echo"` >&/dev/null && exec false || echo "really? use: exit now" ; screen -d'
endif
```